# How to generate blurry image dataset

Tags: image, deep-learning, dataset, barcode, blurry

I've got barcode dataset including 2-d barcodes as well as 1-d ones. i have trouble in decoding barcodes out of focus when testing decoding program using a camera.

I'm thinking DeblurGAN might help and I need blurry barcode dataset.

will it be the only way to apply blur operation with opencv to the dataset?
was wondering if there is any real blur image generator or barcode out of focus dataset?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DeblurGAN itself seems to have code for blurring: https://github.com/KupynOrest/DeblurGAN/tree/master/motion_blur

By the way, training an end-to-end neural network that directly decodes blurry barcodes (instead of a two-step approach of deblurring followed by decoding, not jointly trained) seems worth trying. (Especially if you use "tricks" (correct consideration of the blurring process) from state-of-the-art deblurring methods.)

Note that you can generate synthetic data if you need more data.